# Python relative import different for Django

Tags: python, django

I am experiencing an inconsistency between Django and Spyder (or any non-Django framework).

I make use of `relative imports` for my modules by means of the `.` operator.

This works in Spyder (i.e. non-Django) but as soon as I run my Django server I get the error`ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`.

**My code**:

I have a `helpers.py` file with a few helper functions which I import as follows: `from .helpers import get_SQL_TABLE`. The `helpers.py` is in the same directory as the scripts whence it is called but as mentioned, it leads to an error in Django but not in Spyder.

Comment: Do you have `__ini__.py` file in the same dir?

Comment: Nope but there is a ```init``` one level up which was created with the Django project. Should I create one in the folder where I am? If so, can you give a skeleton of what it should contain?

Comment: It may contain nothing - just create it in the first level of application directory like `your_app/__init__.py`

Comment: I do have ```my_app/__init__.py``` but I am working in one level lower ```my_app/folder/*.py```

Comment: Each nested folder should have this file as well.

Comment: I tried this to no avail. I have however rephrased the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60284568/python-function-import-not-working-in-django. Perhaps I have given the correct information for you to assist further.